# A simple question about C*-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Lemma  If $\|.\|_{\alpha}$ is a C*-norm on $\mathcal{A}\odot\mathcal{B}$, then it is a cross norm.

[image]

Thus, for a unit vector $\xi\in ef\mathcal{H}$, we have  $\|(a\bigotimes b)(\xi)-\xi\|\le 2\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, $\|a\bigotimes b\|=1$.

how to understand  $\|(a\bigotimes b)(\xi)-\xi\|\le 2\varepsilon$. please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, a few details need adjustments. For instance, it should be $$e=\chi_{[(1-\varepsilon)^{1/2},1]}(a\otimes 1),\ \ \ \ \ \ \chi_{[(1-\varepsilon)^{1/2},1]}(1\otimes b).$$

You have, since everything commutes,
$$
f(1\otimes b)f\geq(1-\varepsilon)^{1/2}f,\ \ \ e(a\otimes1)e\geq(1-\varepsilon)^{1/2}e.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
fef-fe(a\otimes b)ef&=fef-(a\otimes1)^{1/2}ef(1\otimes b)fe(a\otimes1)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&\leq fef-(a\otimes1)^{1/2}e(1-\varepsilon)^{1/2}f e(a\otimes1)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&=fef-(1-\varepsilon)^{1/2}fe(a\otimes1)ef\\ \ \\
&\leq fef-(1-\varepsilon)fef\\ \ \\
&=\varepsilon \,fef.
\end{align}
Then
$$
\|\xi-(a\otimes b)\xi\|=\|(fef-fe(a\otimes b)ef)\xi\|\leq\varepsilon.
$$